# How to serve the SQL data prepare only once -- requested independently from more processes (mutex in SQL)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, mutex

**The goal:** The `usp_prepare_data` SQL Server stored procedure should check whether the requested data is prepared or not. If the data is ready to be used, the `usp_prepare_data` should return quickly. If the data is not prepared (there is the condition like *valid to*), then the data should be prepared (it takes like 60 seconds), and after that the usp should return.

**The problem** is that the `usp_prepare_data` is called from a web application, and it can happen that more than one request is created at the time of preparing the data. So, there should be something like mutual exclusion before entering the processing part. Then the condition should be checked, and then the processing should occur if necessary. The second and other requests should wait until they are allowed to check the condition. Using this, the processing part would be done only once.

**Without the mutual exclusion** the other requests find the "data not ready", and launch the process again, in parallel, causing possible problems when mutually locking the processed data.

**With the mutual exclusion**, the other processes would wait for the result about the same time, but the data processing will be done only once, without collisions with the same kind of processing at the same time.

How to do the mutual exclusion inside the stored procedure? The implementation uses SQL Server (the Azure SQL).

**Update:** ... to clarify. Basically, the procedure does 1) check whether new content should be generated, 2) `DELETE`s the obsolete data, and 3) `INSERT`s new data. When called twice in the sequence, it is likely to produce the same result (the input sources change slowly). I am aware of existence of transactions, and that I can wrap the 1), 2), and 3) together in one transaction. Correct me, if I am wrong. The transaction does the actions (consumes the processor time) independently on whether the result will be `COMMIT`ed or `ROLLBACK`ed. This is not what I need. I do not want **only** to avoid corruption of the data table by running the same code in parallel. I want to save the processor time -- to avoid the computation if another one is already running.

Meanwhile, I have found the `sp_getapplock`. Trying...

**More information:** The `usp_prepare_data` actually gets the argument to generate certain portion of the data (think about the short string code that is unique). So, the collision could happen only when the code is the same. All the three phases (check, DELETE, INSERT) are related to the identified portion. The source tables are read `WITH (NOLOCK)`, and the whole destination table should not be locked as a whole.

Comment: Usually you use transactions and/or locking either tables or rows being processed. I'm not sure what kind of objects your process can lock on, it depends on the data being generated. Another way is to do this on request level, ie. in your API you can do the locking before even calling the database

Comment: There is almost no info here to go on. What is the current code for your procedure? What are the tables? What exact "preparing" do you need and why should it take 60 seconds? Does it need to be locked while the application does processing, or can SQL do all the locking and processing?

Comment: I have added the "Update:" part to clarify.

Comment: @Charlieface: The application still runs on one IIS server. However, there is a chance this will be changed. So, I would like to do the locking at the server side. The application then should be "locked" by waiting for the return of the `usp_prepare_data`.

Comment: SQL server includes so called applocks, you can use them to synchronize your requests. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Still no tables or code. We can't work on nothing, please just show what we ask. Why are you using `NOLOCK` are you not aware of the data integrity implications?

Comment: @Charlieface: The actual code has about 1000 lines of SQL, using the external tables to another Azure SQL database. It combines many sources and decides based on the data what variant of processing to do. The `NOLOCK` just means that I do not want to block access to the source that are read (from the external tables). So, the key is the ability to check, DELETE, and INSERT (where the insert is related to combined result from data sources).

Comment: Shared locks don't block anyway (unless you are using serializable), the default on Azure is RC-Snapshot Isolation so it would never block. Still not sure why you are using `NOLOCK`. Either way, cut your procedure down to size, so we can have a [mcve] and can advise you. SQL doesn't work well on generalized sweeping statements, each situation stands on its merits.

Comment: [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to do the mutual exclusion inside the stored procedure?

Use [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).  The simplest way is to use the default "Transaction" ownership of the app lock.  So start a transaction in the proc, call `sp_getapplock`, and then do whatever else in the transaction, eg:

```
begin tran
exec sp_getapplock 'data prep lock', 'Exclusive'

declare @data_prep_needed bit = 1
-- check if data is prepared

if @data_prep_needed = 1
begin
  exec usp_prepare_data 
end
exec sp_releaseapplock 'data prep lock'
commit tran    

-- select data
```